# assigning to a cell a user input value in python 3

Tags: python, magic-square

i've been tasked with

"Ask the user to select a cell in the table and a number to put into the cell" from a partial magic square table.

so far I have

```
numbers = input("Enter two integers: ")
numbers = numbers.split(" ")
y = [int(x) for x in numbers]
print(y)
```

this gives me the numbers, but how do I make them relate to columns and rows? basically, if user inputs '1 and 2', how can I relate them to a column number 1 and row number 2?

thankyou

Answer (score 0):

> Ask the user to select a cell in the table

This code prompts for a string of two numbers and converts the first two numbers separated by space into integers. This is more correct than `y = [int(x) for x in numbers]` because `y` would be a list of ints, not an int itself.

```
numbers = input("Enter two integers: ")
x, y = map(int, numbers.split(" "))
print("row", y, "col", x)
```

> and a number to put into the cell

Assuming you have a 2D list `square` variable that you can access by row and column... Just assign the cell value

```
cell_value = input("Enter a cell value")
square[y][x]  = int(cell_value)
```

Comment: sorry i think i've misunderstood you, what i'm trying to do is convert the two integers inputted into the cell value as it relates to the square variable

Comment: I'm fairly certain this code "Asks the user to select a cell in the table and a number to put into the cell"

Comment: i'm still super confused, where do I go from there? i tried your method but I also did numbers = input("Enter two integers: ")
numbers = numbers.split(" ")
y = [int(x) for x in numbers]
how do i turn those integers into the cell value?

Comment: Yes, I see what you did in your question. All I did was combine the `split` and `int(x) for x in numbers` into a single line of code. You need a square variable to assign a cell value to. I'm sorry I don't understand, but maybe if you were more clear in your question as to what you expect as an output, then I will update my answer. You can find an edit link under your question to include more detail if you wish.